# JavaFX pie chart legend position moved on snapshot

Tags: javafx, pie-chart, snapshot

I am using the Pie Chart from JavaFX and although it shows it properly (left image in the link), when a took a snapshot the legend moves to the right (right image in the link). How can i fix it? The Pie Chart is inside a pane, so the snapshot is made to the pane. I also tried to remove the animation from the Pie Chart, but it did not work either.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeVI4.jpg

This is the snapshot code:

```
    public void saveAsPng(Pane p){
        try{
            WritableImage image = p.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(),null);
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\tempPieChart.png");
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
```

And the code of the Pie Chart is this:

```
public void PieGraph(ArrayList<ArrayList> info, PieChart p) {
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> PieChart = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> lista = info.get(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> valor = info.get(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
         PieChart.add(new PieChart.Data(lista.get(i), valor.get(i)));}

    p.setData(PieChart);
    p.setAnimated(false);
    p.getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Pie.css").toExternalForm());}
```

Comment: Can you paste the rest of the code (that you used to generate the pie chart) as well? We'll need a [mcve] to look at this properly.

Comment: I edited the post and include the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you edited code but didn't provide a [mcve] as suggested, right ;) As you see it's a link, so click on it and read the page, then do as described,  please, without your question is not answerable.